# Jquery - set style for many select - Can I use ID instead of NAME?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm really new at jQuery and bootstrap, if anyone can help I would be very happy. What I want to do is to set the same style to many drop down-menus.

**The code I have now is:**

```
$("select[name='NameOfSelect']").selectpicker({style:'btn-primary', menuStyle:'dropdown-inverse'});
```

**Can I do like this instead and hit all drop downs?**

```
$("select").selectpicker({style:'btn-primary', menuStyle:'dropdown-inverse'});
```

If that's not possible can I target the select with ID instead of NAME, how would that look?

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: "*Can I do like this instead and hit all drop downs?*" Did you try it and see what happened?

Comment: Yes of course but better give the `select` element a `name` or `class` for future manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

the code you wrote in the question works!

```
$("select").selectpicker({style:'btn-primary', menuStyle:'dropdown-inverse'});
```

here is a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/6EncE/

Answer (score 0):

yes you can when you use `$("select")` it will used for all select tags 
if you use

`$("select.hello")`  it will be used only for all select tags with the hello class
`$("select#hello")` for all select with id hello

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$('#select_id').selectpicker({style:'btn-primary', menuStyle:'dropdown-inverse'});
```